# Inverse limit in shape theory

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, homotopy-theory, shape-theory

Is the shape theory of Hausdorff compact spaces complete with respect to the inverse limit operation?--*complete* means that for every inverse system of Hausdorff compact spaces, and the shape morphisms between them, there exists a Hausdorff compact space which is the (inverse) limit (in the shape category) of the system. Remember that the shape morphisms do not have to be--and in general they are not--induced by continuous maps.

WARNING: the shape theory of Hausdorff compact spaces is continuous with respect to inverse limit; this (by itself) doesn't mean that the shape theory of Hausdorff compact spaces is complete--as long as I know, it is as open question as it was since the time when the shape theory of Hausdorff compact spaces was defined.

REMARK: the inverse limit of a shape inverse sequence of Hausdorff compact spaces always exists; the countable case is fine.

Comment: What does 'complete' mean here?

Comment: @FernandoMuro -- I have expanded the text of my question to answer yours.

Comment: You're then talkin about the completeness of a certain *category* rathen than theory.

Comment: @FernandoMuro -- right, it'd be more precise. However *shape category* and *shape theory* are sometimes used as synonyms (*shape theory* rolls the tongue smoother, I think).

Comment: As the wiki entry to shape theory is not very expansive, could you state your question in "layman's terms"?

Comment: I could write a minimal (brief) exposition of *theory of shape* for compact spaces and abstract categories in that compact direction. It'd take a separate MO pseudo-answer though. Otherwise, there is my *Fund.Math.* paper or monograph *Shape Theory* by J.-M. Cordier and T.Porter.